# Java jsoup print class's text

Tags: java, jsoup

how would I get the text that's in the class?

```
<div class="leaderboard-summoner-name">Arcsecond</div>
```

Things I've tried

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.net/leaderboards#/na/1"+ x)
        .timeout(5000)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
        .get();

Elements e = doc.select("div.leaderboard-summoner-name]");
System.out.println(e.text());
```

or

```
Elements e = doc.select("leaderboard-summoner-name");
```

or

```
Elements e = doc.select("div[class=leaderboard-summoner-name]");
```

or

```
Elements e = doc.select("div.leaderboard-summoner-name");
```

Comment: can u tell me what is the `x `value? so that i can check your code

Comment: the x is just a number, like 1

Comment: What is the result do you expect? `Arcsecond`?

Comment: Are you sure that document you received as response contains such div? Have you tried printing `doc`? If it is generated dynamically by JavaScript, then Jsoup can't help you much since it is not browser emulator but HTML parser (you will need to use some other tool, probably Selenium webdriver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the actual html into Jsoup and/or if you load it from a file etc **you get the result you want**.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div class=\"leaderboard-summoner-name\">Arcsecond</div>");
doc.select("div.leaderboard-summoner-name");
Elements e = doc.select("div");
System.out.println(e.text());

// prints Arcsecond as desired
```

Everything works as expected apart from the html that the webserver is returning which, for all purposes, should be put up as another question.